# Best practice when working with web services that return objects?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm currently working with web services that return objects such as a list of files e.g. File array.

I wanted to know whether its best practice to bind this type of object directly to my front end code for example a repeater/listview or whether to first parse it into my own list of "file class" e.g. `customFiles[]`

If the web service changes then it will break my front end code, however if I create my own CustomFile class, then i would only need to change my code in one place to fix the issue, but it just seems like a lot of extra work to create the same classes from a web service, i wanted to know what is the best practice for this type of work.

Comment: Creating a class for this is very simple; it's Data Transfer Object (DTO), just properties, getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delicate balancing act in properly encapsulating implementation details.  Too little encapsulation is a maintenance nightmare as small changes in any area break the application.  Too many layers is a different kind of maintenance headache altogether.

In this particular case I would create a small layer in your application to encapsulate the web service calls.  This will ease your maintenance in both the application and the service as they will be loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have already answered your own problem.  Best practice is to create your own custom class for the reasons you point out, but it is significant extra work.

If the webservice isn't likely to change then just use the existing classes, but if you need to cater for change then create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a class is fine as long as your client knows how to deserialize it.  If it's truly a web service, where you don't have control over both ends of the conversation, it's more common to start with schemas for XML request and response streams.  That decouples the client from the web service a bit more and allows any client that can send XML via HTTP and consume an XML response fair game.